# Application Model Integration

Tags: dxa, web8.5, smarttarget, dxa-java, cis

We are planning to use SDL Tridion in an external web application, where the needs are to include some contents in certain parts of the application, something like banners, news, etc. (XO content based on profiles).

The main application is java based, and external to SDL Tridion environment.

The ways of including this weblets, in a classic scenario, would be with odata content services, querying the broker for component presentations.
In this scenario tha main problem will be the use of XO in the external application.

1- I'm not sure if this is possible using ADPF in an extrernal appliction.

2- But the main question is if the use of DXA could simplify the solution.

- Could the external application made use of DXA only with entities or Regions, in a totally external page of the application, without any matching DXA Page in Tridion?
- Which are the minimum required elements to configure in an external application to make use of microservices like content or xo services?

Sorry if the questions are not very clear, but the main problem is the ways of consuming Tridion bits of information in an external application. Any hints about this will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problem in consuming Tridion (or XO) content in an external web application.

To incorporate content, you can either call any of the Content Delivery API functions from within your web app, to retrieve component presentations etc.
You can also configure ADF and use this in your web app, by adding the jars, and setting up the web.xml so the ADF filter is executed on each page requests (see the steps defined here : https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-E352B7E9-9035-4E93-8BC4-9CCD1729FC3D)

For XO, there are a number of tags that allow you to insert XO content in a webpage. This should also be configured for your webapp (see https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-F7F33BDB-4580-4EFC-B4E8-F8C2F24240D3)

The biggest difficulty is that normally, the XO tags are generated via Tridion Templating using TCDL Tags. These TCDL tags get transformed into Java or .NET tags. Since you are not working with Tridion-published pages, you should write out these Java tags manually.
This java documentation might also help you a lot : https://sdl.dist.sdlmedia.com/distributions/?o=9D0A55C3-3D97-43D8-8C06-8F01FE6AA5F8

Another thing to remember is that it might be useful to create a "dummy" page in Tridion, and use the TCM uri of this page for any parameters of your XO tag.

Comment: To the point on "dummy" pages and similar integrations, @MiguelMiguelez wrote a good [post comparing a few portal integration options](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/portal-integration-scenarios-and-considerations).

Comment: Thanks @Harald, the model that are you explaining is the classic one, in which I see less problem in the integration, appart from the dummy pages that needs to be created. What I need to investigate is the incluson of dxa(dd4t) bits (entities) in an external application.